# Can we give rep to those who flag questions?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, flagging, reputation

On another meta post, a user suggested that we give rep to those who upvote answers, my suggestion is giving rep to those who give helpful flags.

That way we encourage the users to flag questions, speaking about myself, I flagged many questions, very few were closed, so why flagging in the first place? I'm getting no rep out of it, what's in it for me?

That way more questions will be flagged and the site will be cleaned up fast.

Comment: Its it always all about the reputation points and nothing reputation it self?

Comment: @BrunoPereira it's not always about rep, but do you have a better idea to encourage users to flag questions? it's just that rep is the currency of SE

Comment: Considering the size of the close vote queue, I don't think *flagging* (more importantly, the lack thereof) is that much the problem.

Comment: @FEichinger so maybe i should stop flagging then

Comment: For flagging there is a gold badge called Marshal.

Comment: @AvinashRaj why would I want a badge? rep gives me better stuff like I could close questions or whatever, my rep defines who i am on SE

Comment: @Fischer does it? :O

Comment: @BrunoPereira if not why the hell did they create rep? just a point counter?

Comment: @Fischer yes, but of course, it is a indicator of how much the site trusts your actions and nothing else. For abnormalities on that accounts suspension and possible removals are available. In the end reputation has nothing to do with how high that number is. Even a 1 zillion reputation user will get a slap if he decides to be/do something not welcomed on the sites. I personally admire work (no matter from where it comes from, 0 or +10K reputation users) and not the user itself, could not care less about user if all he did to get to high reputation was slack work.

Comment: @BrunoPereira I'm with you on that, like there's a user who got 1k just because he answered `how to install sublime text 2` but what I'm trying to say is giving rep would let users flag more questions, closing more questions, not answering it hoping for an upvote or accepted answer

Comment: @BrunoPereira go through the questions I flagged, you see **very high rep** users answering it because they hope to get rep out of it

Comment: @Fischer I understand the request, I just do not like the idea. People seem to be driven by numbers now a days, you do not do more than needed if there is no reward, if there is a reward then you do. In my experience rewarding people for every action that they do bring mediocrity to those actions, add that to the importance of flagging and we have an issue. Besides, there are already so many rewards implemented with lower responsibility actions, why would this make Ask Ubuntu better? I do not see it, I do not agree with it. Its just my opinion.

Answer (score 5):

Flagging should not be as gamified as voting.  If voting requires thought, flagging is serious.

You shouldn't submit marginal flags.

Adding "points" to something makes it an activity people do to GET points, not because it's something important to do.

People would probably flag marginal things chasing points and inundate moderators with useless or marginal flags.  Marginal problems can be handled with voting or people that have significant rep casting votes to close, delete, etc.

You're asking for points to generate moderator headaches.  100% against that idea.

Comment: I'm asking only for helpful flags to be given rep, not rubbish flags, anyway if a user gives many rubbish flags, his flags wont matter anymore, because mods wont trust him

Comment: I haven't seen the interface, but my knee-jerk is that you don't get flags sorted by user.  You just get a flag-queue like you do in 10k tools.

Comment: @hbdgaf Oh really? :O

Comment: @Bruno You're welcome to clarify if you get a "better" interface ;), but I know I only see a "Flag queue - These things have been flagged.  Perhaps you can help?" agree, disagree, pass.  I can see the user that did the flagging, but I don't have a "/silence item=flags user=somebody" button or a "sort by user" button.

Comment: @hbdgaf Its a secret "only moderators" button and interface.... shhhhh

Comment: @hbdgaf You can see the user that did the flagging?

Comment: @Seth of course he can, there was something called flag weight, now it's removed http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84859/we-dont-need-to-see-flag-weight if you waste his time by flagging anything and everything, he wouldn't bother to look at your flags - if that feature wasn't available he wouldn't be able to know who's wasting his time

Comment: @Fischer I have 10k too and I can't see who cast flags, just the user who posted the answer/question.

Comment: @Seth are you a mod? he said its for mods only and thats why i asked my question in the first place, he knows who is wasting his time and who's not, why not giving rep for the good users flagging questions? if i didn't know that, I wouldn't have asked the question in the first place